# While loop only works as intended after an echo

Tags: php, while-loop, comments, echo

My while loop for updating page values only works when I echo the page value in between each loop.

When the echo is commented out two pages, just after the $old_position value, it gets the same value.

```
if($action2=="delete") {
  //echo("Deleting");
  $sql="delete from pages where id=$mainid";
  $rs=mysql_query($sql, $conn);

  if($old_position !== -1) {
    $sql="select * from pages order by position";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
      $tmp_pos = (int) $row["position"];
      $tmp_id=$row["id"];
      if($tmp_pos > $old_position && $tmp_pos !== -1) {
        $sql2="update pages set position=".($tmp_pos - 1)." where id=\"$tmp_id\"";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
        //var_dump($tmp_pos);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, but why "-1"? It needs to be a int, not a string. Try removing the quotes in '$tmp_pos !== "-1"'. Do a var_dump($tmp_pos) and $old_position and show us the results.

Comment: I added the var_dump at the end of the if statement and this is what came out:
string(1) "9" string(2) "10" string(2) "11" string(2) "12" string(2) "13"

Comment: This is actually the outcome I want and it works as intended.
However, when the var_dump isent running the outcome is still wrong.

Comment: $tmp_pos cecomes something like:
-1, 0, 1, 2, **3, 3,** 4, 5, 6
When i run the code without the echos and var bumps

Comment: The var_dump says it is a string. Try replacing "$tmp_pos=$row["position"];" with "$tmp_pos = (int) $row["position"];" and do the same where you are defining "$old_position". Also, remove the quotes around "-1" in the two ifs.

Comment: The issue still remains.
I have now made sure the $tmp_pos is an int but the outcome is still wring when I'm not dumping the value even though it's correct when I do.

The $old_position is set in the beginning of the page by:
$old_position = mysql_escape_string($_GET['old_position']);

Comment: Wait, you have '!== "-1"'. Remove the quotes around "-1" and leave just one of the two equals: '!= -1'. Do that in the both ifs. You are comparing the var type with "!==", that's probably the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I have already tried that and it didn't help.
I have now updated the post with my latest code.

Comment: Do a var_dump($tmp_pos) and var_dump($old_position) right after "$tmp_pos = (int) $row["position"];".

Comment: The output is:
int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(-1) string(2) "12" int(0) string(2) "12" int(1) string(2) "12" int(2) string(2) "12" int(3) string(2) "12" int(4) string(2) "12" int(5) string(2) "12" int(6) string(2) "12" int(7) string(2) "12" int(8) string(2) "12" int(9) string(2) "12" int(10) string(2) "12" int(11) string(2) "12" int(13) string(2) "12" int(14) string(2) "12" int(15) string(2) "12"

Comment: I just changed the $old_position to always be and int but the problem is still there. It works when I'm printing out the values but its acts strange when I'm just running the loop without any echos or dumping.

Comment: The new var_dumps gives the result of:
int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(-1) int(8) int(0) int(8) int(1) int(8) int(2) int(8) int(3) int(8) int(4) int(8) int(5) int(8) int(6) int(8) int(7) int(8) int(9) int(8) int(10) int(8) int(11) int(8) int(12) int(8) int(13) int(8)